Boolean only intersect certain parts
I am trying to create a vehicle model using the outline gotten from an SVG. , its first turned into a mesh, rather than paths, then dissolved to remove the lines from the SVG. The views are then put along the axis, in the same position that they are orientated.

After cleaning it up as best as I could, im trying to use boolean to create the vehicle based on the front and side views of the vehicle.
I try to use the Boolean intersect to try do this, but it either does nothing, or only creates small bits of the shape.
I have tried normalizing to no avail. The first image is it set to the Exact setting, with both views visible, and the second is the fast setting with only the front view visible.
Is there anyway I could try get this to be done properly?



I don't think the SVG file is very helpful here other than for reference, and booleans will certainly not get you a usable car model, not even a decent starting point to model one.

AFAIK you do need a manifold mesh so that boolean can work properly - and as Duarte already stated - i think too that this is not a good way to model a car. I recommend watching some free yt tutorials about modelling cars.

I concurr. I think you're trying to recreate that cool effect with text that reads differently wether you look at it from the front or the side, but unfortunately that's only a trick of the mind and only really works if you're looking at it from very specific angles. I would not try that for a model as complicated as a car (moreover a sports car which has even more unforgiving curves)
